# Find the N:th Monday in a month with MySQL

Tags: mysql

How to find the *n*-th *weekday* of a month based on `@ref_date`, `@n`, and `@week_day` in MySQL:

```
SET @ref_date = '2012-09-25';
SET @n = 3; #The third week
SET @week_day = 0; #Monday
```

The result should be: `2012-09-17`.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: please notice that some values of @ref_date and @n may cause ´no-way´solutions for example @ref_date='2012-09-25' and @n=1

Comment: please provide a larger set of expected results

Comment: @LuisSiquot, the OP is just using `@ref_date` to represent a month.  So @n=1 would mean the first week in September 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `@weekday` using the standard '0 == Monday', but MySql uses a 1-based standard with '1 == Sunday'.  Assuming we are constrained to say that 0 must equal Monday, you can do this:

```
SET @first_day = DATE_SUB(@ref_date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(@ref_date) - 1 DAY);
SET @first_day_of_week = (DAYOFWEEK(@first_day) - 2) % 7;
SET @solution = DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(@first_day, INTERVAL @n WEEK), INTERVAL ( 7 - ((@week_day - @first_day_of_week + 7) % 7) ) DAY);
```

So as a single query that would be:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD( DATE_SUB( @ref_date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(@ref_date) - 1 DAY),  INTERVAL @n WEEK), INTERVAL ( 7 - ((@week_day - ((DAYOFWEEK(DATE_SUB( @ref_date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(@ref_date) - 1 DAY)) - 2) % 7) + 7) % 7) ) DAY);
```

Comment: This is working fine if I want to get the 'Monday' of the 3th week for September 2012 (is 2012-09-10), but what I want is: the 3th Monday of September 2012 (is 2012-09-17).
I'm trying to change it.

Comment: I had thought that MOD would fix negative numbers, which it apparently doesn't.  Fixed now.

Comment: This is a great solution. I figured out a way myself, but this is much elegant. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

find in one of the solution in SO here

```
SELECT  WEEK(dateField, 5) -
        WEEK(DATE_SUB(dateField, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(dateField) - 1 DAY), 5) + 1
```

Read [`Week of the Month in Mysql`](http://think-robot.com/2009/04/week-of-the-month-in-mysql/)

Comment: i just give a thought. need to apply some logic too.