# Mysql Strting to date like php strtotime "last monday" with dynamic creation in stored procedures

Tags: php, mysql, date, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create the stored procedures to get the string to date in a month like **strotime** in PHP like below.
**eg**

```
 echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";
```

so I have below scenario, how can do below list

1. First Monday.
2. Second saturday.
3. Last Sunday.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571633/find-the-nth-monday-in-a-month-with-mysql), but it's not working. Please help me to fix it. I want to fix in stored procedure. I don't want it in PHP.

Comment: If you don't want it in PHP then you might be better off removing the php tag.

Comment: Remember, MySQL is for the storage and retrieval of relational data, and not much else.

Comment: is there any other way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible stored function to get you what you need. I have assumed that by "last sunday" you mean the last Sunday of the month because of your other 2 being first and second. If you mean the Sunday before today like strtotime would return then this code will not return the correct result. You can use this code as a starting point to refine further. For example you may need to consider the performance on many rows.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS strtotime;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION strtotime(timestring VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS DATE NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE retdate DATE;
  DECLARE testdate DATE;
  DECLARE instancenum INT;
  DECLARE dayname CHAR(3);

  CASE
    WHEN timestring LIKE 'first%' THEN
      SET instancenum = 1;
    WHEN timestring LIKE 'second%' THEN
      SET instancenum = 2;
    WHEN timestring LIKE 'last%' THEN
      SET instancenum = -1;
    ELSE
      SET instancenum = 0;
  END CASE;

  SET dayname = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(timestring,' ',-1),1,3);

  IF instancenum != 0 THEN
    SET testdate = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY);

    IF instancenum < 0 THEN
      SET testdate = DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(testdate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END IF;

    IF DATE_FORMAT(testdate,'%a') = dayname THEN
      IF instancenum < 0 THEN
        SET instancenum = instancenum + 1;
      ELSE
        SET instancenum = instancenum - 1;
      END IF;
    END IF;

    WHILE DATE_FORMAT(testdate,'%a') != dayname OR instancenum!=0 DO
      IF instancenum < 0 THEN
        SET testdate = DATE_SUB(testdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
      ELSE
        SET testdate = DATE_ADD(testdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
      END IF;

      IF DATE_FORMAT(testdate,'%a') = dayname THEN
        IF instancenum < 0 THEN
          SET instancenum = instancenum + 1;
        ELSE
          SET instancenum = instancenum - 1;
        END IF;
      END IF;
    END WHILE;
    SET retdate = testdate;
  ELSE
    SET retdate = NULL;
  END IF;
  RETURN retdate;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

SELECT strtotime('first monday'),strtotime('second saturday'),strtotime('last sunday');
```